# Rsyslog channels change ownership from root

Tags: 10.04, rsyslog

Hello all I am using rsyslog on Ubuntu 10.4 64bit LTS.

the following is the relevant config in /etc/rsyslog.d/60-mylogger.conf

> $template Paul,"%msg%\n"
>
> $outchannel
>   log_rotation_paul,/var/log/paul/events.log,2000,/opt/scripts/log_rotation_script.sh
>
> local0.* $log_rotation_paul;Paul

This should rotate every 2000 bytes

My problem is the the channel directive here causes the ownership defined in /etc/rsyslog.conf to be completely ignored and when my log rotate script is called I don't have the root permissions required to move my log file as its the script runs as rsyslog and the file I am moving requires root permissions.

Any ideas I found this [link](http://kb.monitorware.com/trouble-getting-dynamic-files-work-t10054.html) but unfortunately it does not fix my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, /var/log/paul/events.log is owned by root; yet, you have a script running as the rsyslog user, who cannot move /var/log/paul/events.log.

```
sudo chown -R root.rsyslog /var/log/paul/
sudo chmod 0775 /var/log/paul
sudo chmod g+s /var/log/paul
```

Now, new files in /var/log/paul are always owned by rsyslog. Another solution to use is ACL.